# Sveltekit on change function not being called when added to a component

Tags: javascript, callback, svelte, sveltekit

I've got the following component called `NumericField`:

```html
<script>
    import {isNumber} from "../../helpers/index.js";
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    export let name;
    export let id;
    export let value;
    export let readOnly=false;
    export let disabled=false; // use disabled so we don't submit the value.
    export let styleClass="input w-full py-4 font-medium bg-gray-100 border-gray-200 text-sm\n" +
        "                                  focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:bg-white";


    onMount(() => {
        // if a value is provided for the field then format it and place it in it.
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
            value = formatNumber(value);
            return;
        }

        // if a value was not provided or is not a valid numeric field then set the field value to empty.
        value="";
    });

    const formatNumber = e => {

        // on keyup validate if the value is "", if so return. This is to avoid placing a NaN on the field.
        if (e.target?.value == "") {
            return
        }

        if (parseInt(String(e).replace(/,/g,'')) === NaN) {
            e.target.value = "";
            return
        }

        // if e is not an event (event is of type object) but a number (this will apply for on edit mode or read only fields).
        if (typeof e !== 'object' && (isNumber(e) || isNumber(parseInt(e)))) {
            console.log("not an event. value = ", e)
            // remove all commas (,) from the number and return it.
            return parseInt(String(e).replace(/,/g,'')).toLocaleString("en-US");
        }

        // reformat the given number by adding commas to it but since this is recalculated on the fly first we
        // have to remove any existing commas.
        e.target.value = parseInt(e.target.value.replace(/,/g,'')).toLocaleString("en-US");
    }
</script>

<input
    id={id}
    on:keyup={formatNumber}
    name={name}
    readonly={readOnly}
    disabled={disabled}
    type="text"
    bind:value
    class={styleClass} />
```

And I've got a form in which I'm using the component:

```html
<NumericField
    on:change={updateTotal}
    bind:purchasedPrice
    id="purchasedPrice"
    name="purchased_price" />
```

I'm calling `updateTotal` to calculate the total based on the value inputed in the component, but my function is never called:

```js
const updateTotal = () => {
    console.log("here in updateTotal")
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

What I need at the end of the day is to simply calculate a total based on the value of `NumericField`, so that's the way I'm trying to do it, but before I had something like:

`$: total += total + purchasedPrice`

but `purchasedPrice` is not reactive for some reason, if I do:

`$: console.log("purchasedPrice: ", purchasedPrice)`

I just got `0` once, when the parent component is initialized, but everytime `purchasedPrice` the message is not printed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

After reading the comment, the handler seems like unnecessary. Funny I've been manually dispatching it for a while.

It may be becuase you forgot to dispatch the `change` event from your `NumericField` component.

Try adding in the component:

```
... 
<input on:change   <--- this part 
        id={id}
        on:keyup={formatNumber}
        name={name}
        readonly={readOnly}
        disabled={disabled}
        type="text"
        bind:value
        class={styleClass}
    />
...
```

Comment: why would i need to dispatcht an event? is not enough with `on:change`?

Comment: @MrCujo Without the dispatch, any changes made within the component, such as input updates, remains in the component's scope.

Comment: @yongjulee: Not quite, if you specify `on:event` *without* setting a handler, the event will be forwarded without the need to manually dispatch. So here `<input on:change .../>` should be enough (and also besser, since it keeps the original event object).

Comment: @bruunerh That seems like a valid answer for this case. I just checked on my local server, and it indeed emits changes, without the handler. Thank you for this. I never knew this before.

Comment: @yongjulee is this the only thing I was supposed to update in my code? I mean, I added `on:change` to the component yet the result is the same, the function's still not called

Comment: You should add ```on:change``` to the input inside your component. I checked it on my end, and it logs in the client console successfully.

Comment: that's weird, i did exactly that, did not modify anything else, simply added `on:change` to the `input` field in my component, yet nothing's changed

Comment: @MrCujo Check this out: https://svelte.dev/repl/c1168cffabf04ef4b7c2782710e23bc4?version=3.46.6

Comment: thanks. Perhaps it's me who it's not understanding it correctly, but `on:change` is only triggered when I exit the input field? I thought that `on:change` would be triggered every time the value of the field was changed

Comment: please check my last update to the question, perhaps you could offer some insight with the new given information

Comment: i just need to get the value of the input field in the parent component everytime it changes

Comment: @MrCujo That's the expected behavior. If you want it to get triggered everytime a user enters a new value, or remove it, you may need to use ```on:keydown``` or ```on:keyup```.

Comment: yes, but i'm already using `on:keyup` within the component so if I assign a new listener for keyup it doesn't work. I guess I'll use `on:keydown` but if you know a better way please share it. Other question that remains is: why the value assign to the component is not reactive?

Comment: @MrCujo Maybe because you assigned ```bind:purchasedPrice``` instead of ```bind:value={purchasedPrice}```? I am not the expert but If you are trying to accept anything but a number, I guess try to check for the reactivity and run a function like ```$: purchasedPrice, formantNumber()``` where the function checks for the number and reformat. I looked up my UI kit, and it seems to be what I have done in the past.

Comment: @yongjulee yes, that's correct. I'll mark your response as the correct answer, but since I had updated my question with the piece you just answered please add it to your response for future reference. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it